# Solving a system with Newton's method in matlab?

Tags: numerical-methods, matlab

I have the following non-linear system to solve with Newton's method in matlab:

```
x²+y²=2.12
y²-x²y=0.04
```

What is the linear equation system to be solved? Should I calculate the Jacobian matrix? I should use the starting variables x=1, y=1 and solve it with a matlab program with an error less than 10^-6. .Can you tell me how to do it?

### Update

Here is my solution that is the same as matlab's solver. It's just like Newton for scalar and in vector form:

```
>>f=inline('x(1)^2+x(2)^2-2.12; x(2)^2-x(1)^2*x(2)-0.04]');
>>x=fsolve(f,x)
equation solved
x=
1.006852730995833
1.051783055209322
>>while dxnorm>0.4e-6 & iter<10
f=[x(1)^2+x(2)^2-2.12;x(1)^1-x(1)^2*x(2)-0.4];
J=[2*x(1) 2*x(2);-2*x(1)*x(2) 2*x(2)*x(1)^2];
dx=-J\f
x=x+dx
dxnorm=norm(dx,inf), iter=iter+1;
end
>>x, iter
x=1.006852730995833
1.051783055209322
```

Comment: You will definitely need the [Jacobian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton's_method#Generalizations). Sounds like a homework question though? What have you tried and have you searched on internet already?

Comment: Do you need to implement the algorithm or use built in functions?

Comment: @Daryl I updated with a solution. Please have a look. Thanks for commenting.

Comment: @Raskolnikov Yes, it's homework and I've solved it now. Please have a look. Thanks for commenting.

Comment: Looks good to me. But you should put that in a proper answer, not in the question.

Comment: It looks good to me also.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately, your update doesn't convince me you did the correct job, based on your script, your `x` variable is already the answer and residing in the workspace, the second time when your own scripts are being executed, only one iteration has been made, not the whole Newton's method.

If you are allowed to use `Symbolic Toolbox` to compute the Jacobian, there is a more universal way of doing instead of just carrying out a problem-oriented script. Here is a modified version to match your notation of an old implementation of mine for Newton's method, and this could be easily vectorized for a multi-dimensional nonlinear equation system using `varargin` input, and do a string size check on the inline function you passed to the following function.

```
function [s J] = newton(f,p0,tol,MaxIter)
format long
x = sym('x'); y = sym('y'); 
F = f([x,y]);
% Compute the Jacobian matrix symbolically
J = jacobian(F);
invJ = inv(J);
s = zeros(MaxIter,2);
s(1,:) = p0;
dsnorm = inf;
iter = 1;

while dsnorm>tol && iter<MaxIter
    ds = -subs(invJ,[x y],s(iter,:))*f(s(iter,:));
    s(iter+1,:) = s(iter,:) + ds';
    dsnorm = norm(ds,inf);
    iter = iter+1;
end
s = s(1:iter,:);

end
```

This function accepts input `f` as an inline function, `p0` is the initial guess, `tol` is the tolerance and `MaxIter` is the maximum iteration allowed, if the vectorized version of your input is:

```
  >>f=inline('[p(:,1).^2+p(:,2).^2-2.12; ...
   p(:,2).^2-p(:,1).^2.*p(:,2)-0.04]','p');
```

Then

```
>>s = newton(f,[1 1],0.4e-6,10)
```

would return:

```
s =
   1.000000000000000   1.000000000000000
   1.006666666666667   1.053333333333333
   1.006852189012140   1.051784722315402
   1.006852720492674   1.051783057117558
   1.006852720493521   1.051783057115295
```

As you can see the last output is different from yours, because basically what you had was `fsolve` output, however `fsolve` use `trust-region-dogleg` algorithm by default, not Newton's method, if your output coincides with `fsolve`'s result, then your implementation should have a problem.